# Bootstrap split button dropdown with a caret before main button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a reverse [split button dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split). But have some issues with rounded corners when it's rendered (the grouping doesn't work as I expect them).

```
<div class="btn-group padded">
    <!-- Dropdown -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">  
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>   
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 0</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /Dropdown -->
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Option 2</button>
</div>
```

It can be seen in the following [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rBFW9/2/). Any ideas for a fix?

**UPD**:
Right now I use the following css hack:

```
.btn-group>.btn:first-child:not(:last-child) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

But I'm not sure why `.btn-group>.btn:first-child:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle)` is used for that behaviour in bootstrap styles.

Comment: **Stop** rolling back the tag edit.  We **already** have a tag for Bootstrap 3 with well over thirteen hundred questions.  We do not need a second tag for it.  If you disagree with the name, that is an appropriate thing to discuss on Meta.

Comment: Since you continue to add in your incorrect tag, I am locking this. *Please do not continue to do this after the lock has expired.*

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since no one provided an alternative workaround within bootstrap, here's my solution from update above:

```
.btn-group>.btn:first-child:not(:last-child) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, create a CSS selector which will be called *after* Bootstrap's CSS is applied, and simply specify the border radius override:

```
.btn.dropdown-toggle.beforetoggle {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
```

Add that to your button:

```
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle beforetoggle"/>
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p8eZr/1/). Presto.

Answer (score 1):

The rounded corners is coming from the `border-radius: 4px;` style in bootstrap.css for the .btn class.

You can override this for a specific button (I would add a CSS class to the button on your page and add the override to that CSS class).

Comment: First item in `.btn-group` shouldn't be rounded on both sides unless it also is the last item. Looks like a bug to me. The question is about bootstrap's LESS styling, rather than CSS in general. Anyways, I posted a pull request, will see what's the official response.